# Исключение при попытке копирования std::substr()

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Есть следующий код:

```
case 10501:
GetWindowTextA(hMyEditControl, &static_text[0], 20);
try {
    drive_letter_string = static_text.substr(0, 1);
    SetWindowTextA(hMyStaticControl, drive_letter_string.data());
}
catch(const std::out_of_range & err)
{
    MessageBoxA(hWnd, "Sorry error while copying data to string", "Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}    
break;
```

Собственно говоря, в эдите у меня есть текст следующего вида: "C:\\bla-bla" (без кавычек, естественно). Я пытаюсь скопировать в переменную `drive_letter_string` букву C и ловлю исключение. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то мне не нравится, что Вы копируете текст по адресу `&static_text[0]`. Как правило, объект `std::string` устроен внутри довольно сложно и напоминает больше `list`, чем `vector`, т.е. данные в нем не обязательно расположены последовательно.

Лучше копируйте в обычный строковый буфер `char[]`, а потом, если нужно, делайте из него `std::string`.

Comment: так это ж быдлокод, не?

Comment: Почему? Использование типов Си в С++ никто в принципе не воспрещает, там, где это действительно необходимо.

Comment: Особенно это касается всяких WinAPI и прочих низкоуровневый вещей.

Comment: Если боитесь массивов, можно использовать vector<char>

Comment: Память, выделенная под `std::string` [гарантированно представляет собой один блок][1] для случая, если `length > 0`.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать , мда, интересно. Надо будет покопаться со всем этим.

Comment: IMHO тут все достаточно понятно (раньше внимательно не смотрел). 

Данные копируются в "буфер" string (допустим там достаточно места). Поле "длины" данных в буфере естественно не меняется (допустим было 0). 

Соответственно .substr() бросает исключение.

Comment: @avp, std::string предоставляет динамически расширяемый буфер, так что возиться с выделением памяти программисту не нужно. Места в этом буфере всегда достаточно.

Comment: @Asen, "места достаточно", если пользоваться методами класса string. 

Думаю, что GetWindowTextA положит туда байты напрямую.

Comment: @Asen Это верно только при условии отсутствия прямой манипуляции над символьным буфером (`std::string::c_str()`, `std::string::data()` и вещи типа `&string[0]`). При работе с `WinAPI` этого обычно не избежать.

Answer (score 3):

*Очень нехороший код вы написали.*

- Происходит использование `exception'ов` для `flow control'a` на ровном месте. Эксепшны - **для исключительных ситуаций,** а не для ситуации, когда вам лень проверить длину строки.
- `SetWindowTextA` не швыряет `C++` исключения, поэтому ее можно смело вынести из блока.
- Не проверяются коды ошибки от функций `WinAPI`.
- В обработчике исключений написана ересь - `std::out_of_range` не имеет никакого отношения к копированию данных.
- `SetWindowTextA` принимает `LPCSTR`, то есть нуль-терминированную строку, а вы передаете методу результат `std::string::data()`, который [не содержит символа `\0` в конце.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/)
- Ваш код элементарно переделывается, если спросить с помощью метода `::GetWindowTextA` у контрола первую букву, а дальше *(в зависимости от того, совпадает она с вашими ожиданиями или нет, и если метод `WinAPI` не сфейлился)* установить ее путем вызова `::SetWindowTextA`.

> - Не забудьте про то, что строка должна быть нуль-терминированной.

Comment: out_of_range имеет прямое отношение к взятию подстроки.

Comment: @mikillskegg Подразумевалось, что `"Sorry error while copying data to string"` не соотносится с реальным эксепшном от `substing`. Ну, и, опять же, см. первый пункт (про ненужность `try-catch` вообще).

Comment: Мне кажется, что по сравнению с главной проблемой - попыткой прямого копирования в string - все это не так принципиально. 

И насчет линейного расположения данный в стринге. Да, стандарт С++11 требует этого, а С++03 - нет, хотя реально все так и обстоит. Был неправ. Но все равно вот так копировать данные в стринг - полное безобразие.

Answer (score 1):

Вот я, к сожалению, не совсем согласен с [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg), так как сам вызов копирования текста в `static_text[0]`:

```
  GetWindowTextA(hMyEditControl, &static_text[0], 20);
```

не находится внутри защищенного блока `try`, поэтому, эксепшн не может возникать там. Исключение возникает в одной  из двух строк. Мне почему-то кажется, что во второй строке...

---

А вообще, тут надо дебажить самому. Код-то не сложный, ошибку будет найти нетрудно. Проверьте где возникает исключение, также убедитесь, что для `static_text` выделено достаточное количество памяти.